# how to add an onclick event in an implementation of AbstractHasData in gwt

Tags: gwt, onclick

how to add an onclick event in an implementation of AbstractHasData. I think I have to add CellPreviewEvent but Im having diffculties doing that. Please let me know if my approach is correct and how to add CellPreviewEvent.

```
public class TLayout extends AbstractHasData<Summary> {

private LayoutPanel main;
private ScrollPanel scroller;
private FlowPanel contents;
private ListDataProvider<Summary> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Summary>();
public TLayout(int pageSize,
        ListDataProvider<Summary> dataProvider) {

    super(new LayoutPanel(), pageSize, dataProvider.getKeyProvider());
    this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    main = (LayoutPanel) getWidget();

    main.addStyleName("TLayout");

    contents = new FlowPanel();
    scroller = new ScrollPanel(contents);

    main.add( scroller );

    scroller.addStyleName("scroller" );
    contents.addStyleName("contents");

    main.setSize("100%", "100%");

    main.setWidgetLeftRight(scroller, 0, Unit.PCT, 0, Unit.PCT);
    main.setWidgetTopBottom(scroller, 0, Unit.PCT, 0, Unit.PCT);


}
@Override
protected void renderRowValues(SafeHtmlBuilder sb,
        List<Summary > values, int start,
        SelectionModel<? super Summary > selectionModel)
        throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.debug( "TLayout.renderRowValues() ENTER" );

    for (Summary summary : values) {
        sb.appendHtmlConstant(createCard( summary ));
  }
}

private String createCard(Summary summary ) {

    StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();

    builder.append("<div class='summary'>");
    ....
    .....
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using CellTable or CellList? It sounds like the CellList may solve your problem.

Comment: I want the widgets to be added horizontally that's why. Is there a way to add cells horizontally in cellTable or CellList like in a FlowPanel.

Comment: Yes, CellList is what you want to do. You can create a simple AbstractCell and set the style of the cell to do float: left. You will extends AbstractCell and render it using the render function. Then set a style on the cell for something like summaryCell. In the css just set the float: left; http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

Comment: By using float it will also resize correctly and the cells that would normally be cut off with wrap around when the window gets smaller

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a SelectionModel. You can add a SelectionModel to the abstract has data that will handle selection of your summary class.

```
private final SingleSelectionModel<Summary> summarySelectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Summary>() {
    {
        addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
                Summary summary = getSelectedObject();
                if (summary != null) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

tlLayout.addSelectionModel(summarySelectionModel);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I added this.addSelectionModel(new SingleSelectionModel<Summary>() {
    {
        addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
                Summary summary = getSelectedObject();
                if (summary != null) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
};); in constructor its still not working.